# C++: String Compare

Tags: c++, string, boolean

I am currently baffled on why my program isn't executing the way it should be. Whenever I run it, it only executes the first cout & cin statement and completely bypasses the second one. The program needs to ask for two names and stores them in string objects.

It should then report whether or not, ignoring case, they are the same (as in testing if the name "jack" is the same as "JACK" and it will show that the names are the same ignoring the differences in lower/uppercase lettering.) The question gave the two needed headers for the program, so you'll see the bool and string headers in the beginner.

Here is my current code: http://pastebin.com/Ju0MjkfP

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string upperCaseIt(string s);
bool sameString (string s1, string s2);

int main ()
{
    char name1, name2;

    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin >> name1;

    cout << "Enter another name and I will test if they are the same.";
    cin >> name2;

    if (name1==name2)
       cout << name1 << " is the same as " << name2 << endl;

    if (name1!=name2)
        cout << name1 << " is not the same as " << name2 << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
bool sameString (char name1)
{
     if (name1)
        return true;
     else
         return false;
}
```

Edit: I inputted "jack" and "JACK" to test it.

Any hints would be appreciated; Thanks.

Comment: a note for future questions: please include the test input you gave to your program, the output it gave, and what you expected it to give

Answer (score 3):

When you declare

```
char name1, name2;
```

you declare two *single-character* variables. If you want a string you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
std::string name1, name2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::string`, not `char`. A `char` variable will only hold one single character (e.g. an 'a', but not a full name like "Alfred".

So you should do

```
std::string name1, name2;
```

instead of

```
char name1, name2;
```

Furthermore, your `sameString` doesn't really seem complete yet, it only checks if your `name1` variable is != 0

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the other correct answers, the reason it "skips" the second cin is that input is buffered. When it asks you for a name, you type several characters (e.g., Mike). The following line calls the `operator>>` method on cin to store the data you entered. If you had declared `name1` as a `std::string`, it would read up to the newline character, save the string "Mike" in the variable, and discard the newline. At that point, every character you typed will have been read in, so nothing is left in the buffer.

However, you declared `name1` as a `char` -- a single character. So when C++ does the `cin >> name1` call, it rightly realizes that it can only store one letter, so that's all it reads. That means `name1` is just 'M', and there's still stuff left that hasn't been read yet. In this case, "ike". So the next time it needs to read sometime, it doesn't need to wait on you to type anything else. It just continues reading from the buffer you've already filled.